# Woocommerce changing get_quantity() to get_attribute()

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to change the output of a plugin from get_quantity() to get_attribute('pa_mennyiseg'). I've tried it without any success, I am just kind of getting in to php.

Would anyone be able to help me out with this?

```
            $product_id = $termek['product_id'];
            $sku = $termek->get_product()->get_sku();
            $tetel = $tetelek->addChild('tetel');
            $tetel->addChild('megnevezes',htmlspecialchars($termek->get_name()));
            $tetel->addChild('azonosito',$sku);
            $tetel->addChild('mennyiseg',$termek->get_quantity());
            $tetel->addChild('mennyisegiEgyseg','');
            if(round($termek->get_total(),2) == 0) {
                $tetel->addChild('nettoEgysegar',0);
                $tetel->addChild('afakulcs',0);
            } else {
                $tetel->addChild('nettoEgysegar',round($termek->get_total(),2)/$termek->get_quantity());
                $tetel->addChild('afakulcs',round( ($termek->get_total_tax()/$termek->get_total()) * 100 ) );
            }

            $tetel->addChild('nettoErtek',round($termek->get_total(),2));
            $tetel->addChild('afaErtek',round($termek->get_total_tax(),2));
            $tetel->addChild('bruttoErtek',round($termek->get_total(),2)+round($termek->get_total_tax(),2));
            $tetel->addChild('megjegyzes','');
```